# Text documents with fixed length underline segments fill-able by hand, typewriter, or entering character strings in LaTeX source

Tags: forms, underline

I would like to create simple text documents in which lines and paragraphs may contain underline segments (\rule{}{}) of various preset lengths. Compiling the document with the underline segments only and printing gives a paper document that may be filled in by hand or by typewriter.

I would also like to produce documents that look as though they were filled in by typewriter, but are in fact produced by entering text in typewriter font in the LaTeX source.

The minimal working example achieves the desired effect, but only by impractical manual fiddling to determining the length of the underline \ul{} following the underlined text \ultt{} required to get the right length.

One obviously wants a way of computing the length of the underlined typewriter font text entered in a segment and subtracting it from the preset length of the underline segment to get the length of the underline extension.

The minimal working example code should make the idea clear.

Obviously also it would be nice to have some more direct way to achieve the result with an existing package, but I've searched for hours on several occasions without finding anything.

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in, left=1.00in, right=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{ulem} % Set depth of underline
\def\ul#1{\rule[-1.8pt]{#1}{0.4pt}}
\def\ultt#1{\rule[-1.8pt]{0em}{0.4pt}\uline{\texttt{#1}}\rule[-1.8pt]{0em}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}

\vspace{3ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}  % Guide line
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\rule{3.125in}{0.4pt}\rule{0.25in}{1pt}\rule{3.125in}{0.4pt}}  % Guide line
\vspace{1ex}
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Seller \ul{2.75in}, of \ul{3.13in}}
\vspace{1ex}
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Seller \ultt{Mr. Gargantua}\ul{1.73in}, of \ultt{France}\ul{2.69in}}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}   % Guide line

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would look at \textField (eforms package).  Not only can they be filled in using most PDF readers, you can print them empty.  Normally the form does not include lines, but perhaps you can initialize the fields with _____.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of achieving this.

You could use the `\rlap` command on the typewriter text, so that it the `\ul` command that comes after it starts where it starts, and the `\ul` can then be same length as the length you originally inserted. (Remove the underline underneath the typewriter text, as it is no longer needed.)

```
\newcommand{\mytt}[1]{\rlap{\texttt{#1}}}

\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Seller \ul{2.75in}, of \ul{3.13in}}
\vspace{1ex}
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Seller \mytt{Mr.\ Gargantua}\ul{2.75in}, of \mytt{France}\ul{3.13in}}
```

(Since you're not using `\underline`, you then don't need the `ulem` package then, or to redefine `\ULdepth`.)

By the way, it's the parfill option to parskip that is making the `mbox`es necessary. I'd take that out. Without it you could simply do:

```
Seller \ul{2.75in}, of \ul{3.13in}

\vspace{1ex}
Seller \mytt{Mr.\ Gargantua}\ul{2.75in}, of \mytt{France}\ul{3.13in}
```

Personally, though, I'd go even lazier. I'd load the `xhfill` package, and just define a command to automatically make the blanks the right length to fill in the line.

```
\usepackage{xhfill}
\newcommand{\mytt}[1]{\rlap{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myulfill}{\xrfill[-1.8pt]{0.4pt}}
...
Seller \myulfill, of \myulfill

\vspace{1ex}
Seller \mytt{Mr.\ Gargantua}\myulfill, of \mytt{France}\myulfill
```

Then you don't have to manually calculate *anything*.

However, this will make the blanks of equal size. If you don't want that, you might only want to use it for the last blank on the line, to ensure the blank is exactly the right width to fill the line without having to get it by trial and error.

It is also possible to do what you suggested; get the width of the insertion and subtract it:

```
\newlength{\ullength}
\setlength{\ullength}{2.75in}
\newlength{\fieldwidth}
\settowidth{\fieldwidth}{\texttt{Mr.\ Gargantua}}
\addtolength{\ullength}{-\fieldwidth}

\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Seller \ultt{Mr.\ Gargantua}\ul{\ullength} ...}
```

But I wouldn't recommend going that way.

Comment: I didn't know \rlap, your code does exactly what I want with minimum overhead.